# Swagger generated java objects won't map JSON request correctly

Tags: java, rest, yaml, swagger, openapi

Here's my `JSON` `POST` request example:

```
{
    "batch": {
        "header": {
            "id": 123,
            "id2": 234,
            "msg": 4,
            "time": "01",
            "id3": "str1234"
        },
        "dataStuff": {
            "prod": {
                "bi": "true",
                "pd": "true"
            },
            "nmb": "str1234",
            "date": "2012-12-13",
            "sett": {
                "type": "str1234",
                "net": "str1234",
                "general": "str1234",
                "date": "str1234",
                "low": 12,
                "high": 12
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Swagger openapi 3.0.0 `.yaml` schema:

```
schemas:
    batch:
      type: object
      properties:
        header:
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
            id2:
              type: string
            msg:
              type: string
            time:
              type: string
            id3:
              type: string
        dataStuff:
          type: object
          properties:
            prod:
              type: object
              properties:
                bi:
                  type: string
                pd:
                  type: string
            nmb:
              type: string
            date:
              type: string
              format: date
            sett:
              type: object
              properties:
                type:
                  type: string
                net:
                  type: string
                general:
                  type: string
                date:
                  type: string
                low:
                  type: string
                high:
                  type: string
```

After generating my java models using the above yaml, I send a `POST` request.  I print out that request's body and get:

```
class batch{
    header: null
    dataStuff: null
}
```

`@JsonProperty` has failed in mapping all values in all nested objects.  What am I doing wrong?  I don't know any other way of writing the `.yaml` to support nested objects.

Comment: How do your Java models look like? How do you send a POST request? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: There is a java model generated for the top level object and one each for each nested object.  I'm sending a post request in json format via postman.  the expected outcome is for swagger's auto generated java objects with jackson mapper annotation `@jsonproperty` to automatically map my values to each object.  this is not the case despite swagger generating the objects using the above yaml.  this is why im posting the yaml which is generating the objects, it isn't working correctly.

Comment: what's bugging me is swagger is successfully generating models from my yaml, but these objects won't allow the incoming json to be mapped to it.
i generated the yaml with my example json, yet the objects which swagger generates via the yaml aren't actually mappable...

Comment: What technology are you using for defining REST endpoints? Are you using Spring?

Comment: yes spring boot

Comment: Did you annotate your endpoint methods' argument with `@RequestBody` annotation? Like follows:

`public YourResultObject postMyRequest(final @RequestBody YourRequestObject yourRequestObject)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200614/discussion-between-rozart-and-notachance).